# Как разделить значения столбца по условию?

Tags: python, pandas

Не могу найти описание, как работает нижеприведенная функция по разделению столбца:

```
df['В'], df['С'] = zip(*df['A'].map(lambda x: x.split('.')))
```

Понимаю, что столбец А делится с разделением по точке на В и С, но не могу найти как добавить дополнительные условия. Допустим, разделение столбца А на те же В и С также по запятой.

Comment: приведите пример входного и выходного набора данных (data sets)

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ. хотел привести примеры по вашему запросу, но пока разбирался как это сделать в соответствии с правилами сайта..

Comment: у меня почему то с регулярными выражениями не работает. выдает "too many values to unpack". сейчас разбираюсь. а в предложенном варианте с Series.str нет добавления новых столбцов к разделяемой таблице. ну в Вашем примере нет. попробую сам реализовать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим у нас есть след. DF:

```
In [66]: df
Out[66]:
                    A
0         aaa.bbbbbbb
1  ccc,xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2           xxxxx.zzz
3              ww,ddd
```

для того чтобы разбить строки по разделителю можно воспользоваться встроенными в Pandas методами - [Series.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) или [Series.str.split()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
In [67]: df.A.str.split(r'\.|,', expand=True)
Out[67]:
       0               1
0    aaa         bbbbbbb
1    ccc  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2  xxxxx             zzz
3     ww             ddd

In [68]: df.A.str.extract(r'([^,\.]*)[,\.]+(.*)', expand=True)
Out[68]:
       0               1
0    aaa         bbbbbbb
1    ccc  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2  xxxxx             zzz
3     ww             ddd
```

**UPDATE:** как добавить новые столбцы одной командой:

```
In [54]: df[['B','C']] = df.A.str.extract(r'([^,\.]*)[,\.]+(.*)', expand=True)

In [55]: df
Out[55]:
                    A      B               C
0         aaa.bbbbbbb    aaa         bbbbbbb
1  ccc,xxxxxxxxxxxxxx    ccc  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2           xxxxx.zzz  xxxxx             zzz
3              ww,ddd     ww             ddd
```

можно переделать ваш метод, чтобы он использовал RegEx (регулярные выражения) - тогда он тоже будет работать:

```
In [71]: df['B'], df['C'] = zip(*df['A'].map(lambda x: re.split(r'\.|,', x)))

In [72]: df
Out[72]:
                    A      B               C
0         aaa.bbbbbbb    aaa         bbbbbbb
1  ccc,xxxxxxxxxxxxxx    ccc  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2           xxxxx.zzz  xxxxx             zzz
3              ww,ddd     ww             ddd
```

но встроенные методы, по-моему, понятнее и элегантнее

PS к тому же при помощи `Series.str.extract()` - очень удобно разделить строку, например, по **первой** запятой или точке

Сравнение производительности для DF с 40.000 строк:

```
In [73]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [74]: df.shape
Out[74]: (40000, 3)

In [75]: %timeit zip(*df['A'].map(lambda x: re.split(r'(?:\.|,)', x)))
1 loop, best of 3: 268 ms per loop

In [76]: %timeit df.A.str.extract(r'([^,\.]*)[,\.]+(.*)', expand=True)
1 loop, best of 3: 245 ms per loop

In [77]: %timeit df.A.str.split(r'\.|,', expand=True)
1 loop, best of 3: 270 ms per loop
```